# UI-Grid does not refresh the dynamic style after modify the modal data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

The test button change the model data, the cell data changed, but not the style. activate the changed cell and click away update trigger the style change. I try to call core.refresh(). but does not work.

```
$scope.changeData = function() {
    $scope.gridOptions.data[1].company = "Velity";
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/A9Vpxs6OgIfkaLT3Gg2y?p=preview

Comment: It seems like the cellClass function gets called only when the grid is re-rendered. If you scroll it then the row get's correctly colored.

Answer (score 0):

For me calling gridApi.core.notifyDataChange after changing data worked.

An example within controller:

```
module.controller('myController', function ($scope, uiGridConstants, ...other deps) {
    $scope.gridOptions= {

        //...blah blah,

        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        }
    };

    //...

    $scope.something = function() {
        $scope.gridOptions.data[1].something = 'Something';
        $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.EDIT);
    }
}
```